# Auto generate custom functions in web service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

Is it possible to automatically generate web services functions from the backend at runtime in  c#?

What I am trying to do is

1. I will have a code generator which will generate data access code from MSSQL database schema in C# which can be use for basic CRUD operation.
2. Will build a tool (interface) which will use that basic data schema and generate custom functions in web service using some kind of field mapping.
3. The custom functions generated in step 2 will then be available in the web service as a function call (May be business rule validation or as data view)

Any idea or some starting point for this kind of scenarios are welcome.

Thanks alot.

Comment: See [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx).